# Perl my and our variable in for loop gives misleading results

Tags: perl

```
perl -e 'print for (map {for (my $i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {print $_ * $i}} (1,2,3))'
```

gives:   ***0 1 2 0 2 4 0 1 4***

```
perl -e 'print for (map {for (our $i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {print $_ * $i}} (1,2,3))'
```

gives:   ***0 1 2 0 2 4 0 3 6***

Kindly enlighten me on the above discrepant results

Comment: Even more: `perl -e 'print for (map {for (my $i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {print $_}} (1,2,3))'` outputs `111133330123`

Comment: `perl -e 'print for (map {for (my $i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {print ${\$_} * $i}} (1,2,3))'` gives same result as version with `our` does.

Comment: This is indeed strange. I simplified this a little bit, as the inner for returns an empty list.  perl -e 'map {for (my $i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {print $_}} (1,2,3)'. Running that line in the debugger gives the expected result. perl -d -e 'map {for (my $i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {print $_}} (1,2,3)'

Comment: Another one:perl  -e 'map {for (my $i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {print $_}} (1,2,3,4,5)'
gives 1111144444012344444455555

Comment: A bug as noted in the duplicate. Interestingly the first version crashes my Strawberry Perl 5.18.2 during destruction (but not in debug mode).